# How to set initial weights in Convolution2D in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

The syntax for adding Convolution2D layer is Keras is 
https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d. I am unable to pass "weights" argument correctly. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
conv1_1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                            weight_and_bias=[weight, biases], name='conv1_1')(input)
```

The shape of weight is (nb_filter, nb_channel, filter_size, filter_size), shape of biases is (nb_channel,)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a list of `numpy` arrays to set as initial weights.

For `Convolution2D`, weights list have two items, one in shape `(nb_filter, nb_channel, nb_row, nb_col)` and bias in shape `(nb_filter,)`.

According to the author of Keras:

> If you have doubts about what these shapes are, you can simply
>   instantiate your layer then call `get_weights()`, and look at the
>   output. The argument weights, and also the method
>   `set_weights(weights)`, expect exactly the same format as the output
>   of `get_weights()`.